# Finding a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find a sequence of numbers $A_n \in \mathbb{R} $ (not infinitely many of them being zero) such that

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \cdot A_n = 1$

and

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-n \cdot (A_n)^{2}}{n}} = 0 \space \space \space $ ?

( It is also required that the latter series doesn’t have infinitely many zeroes )

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Is there some background to this?

Comment: Those sequences appeared to me while I was studying the Dirichlet Eta function (alternate Zeta).

Comment: What have you tried? Is $A_n \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: Yes, and the equality of doesn’t hold because the alternate sum of inverted square roots wont converge to 1.

Comment: The equality *of* -> don’t consider the *of*, I mistyped

Comment: Im not convinced that *some* of the $A_n$ couldn't be equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. Additionally, Im not convinced that there isn't a sequence of real numbers that turn the second equation into a summation of complex numbers that happen to satisfy the equation. In any case, please include your work in the body of the question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/431789

Comment: Some of them could, but not all. I understand your second non-conviction, and I agree that the second series could be of complex numbers, though I’m assuming that there is a real valued series also, and that is the one I’m seeking. I have my work written in my papers, I’ll get to Latex them.

Comment: Have you tried taking $A_n=1/\sqrt n$ for $n \geq 3$ and solving the two equations to find $A_1$  and $A_2$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that’s indeed a good idea. The “problem” is that when I do so, the second series yields infinitely many zeros (for n >= 3). I know I only asked the first sequence not to have infinitely many zeroes, but the fact is that the second sequence should also obey that. I’ll edit the question. And thanks :)

Comment: You can pick $A_n=$*anything* (for example $A_n=2^{-n}$) for $n \ge 3$, and then solve for $A_1, A_2$. Obviously, these two numbers won't have a nice closed form, but they exist.

Comment: @Crostul You’re right, and it turns out that the closed form gets a little fuzzy in terms of the Eta Function itself. But truth is my question is not complete, and there is additional constraints relating the A_n ‘s . As David Diaz suggested above, I’ll upload the whole development of my question soon.